# AdMob on iPhone occasionally opens its browser and freezes app

Tags: iphone, ipad, admob, adwhirl

Just encountered the problem with integration of AdMob into my iPad application.

The problem is that sometimes AdMob opens its own browser when device even not touched and then nothing happens (no ad is loaded in that browser) and UI doesn't react at all, so eventually I get my app frozen.

AdMob is integrated through AdWhirl, but problem is not there. I put breakpoint to adViewWillPresentScreen: and stack trace shows only AdMob's classes and no AdWhirl.

Switched AdWhirl log into debug mode, but can not see anything suspicious.

I haven't seen such problem on iPhone.

Has anyone faced this problem and is there any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem got solved by updating AdMob SDK to the latest version.